# Sharepoint 2013 app custom action - how to get parameters using JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, custom-actions

I'm learning to write SharePoint 2013 applications. I added menu item custom action, and now I'm trying to add some functionality to App.js. 
Custom action contains the following code:

```
<UrlAction Url="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}" />
```

And I'm trying to get parameters like "SPListItemId" and "SPListId" in App.js. I found the following code:

```
 function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

I'm calling this function like, but it doesn't work:

```
var SPListId = getParameterByName('ListId');
```

Please tell me where is my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```js
var SPListId = getParameterByName('SPListId');
```

Comment: Hey Kai. Thank you for answer. But the problem is still there. Function getParameterByName(name) uses only location.search, maby it should get data from the document?
Or how to use getParameterByName('SPListId'); correctly?

Comment: You're right, it uses location.search, in other words it tries to get parameter value from you query string. For example for following url `http://my.app.com/?SPListId=4` the function will return `4`. If `SPListId` is missing from query string, it returns nothing.

Comment: When application has started, the document is loaded too. I got the applications url through the document, but there is no tag with **ListId**. From what object I can retrieve any staff to use getParameterByName?

Comment: Which List Id are you expecting on `Pages/Default.aspx`?

Comment: My action begins when the button in list item menu is activated. After that, the application is loaded on Default.aspx. I wanna get **ItemId** and **ListId**, where the application was called. I thought that this information can be obtained from a string _<UrlAction Url="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}" />_ by using JS script in App.js

Comment: You're absolutely correct, your code should work for list item menu. And when get redirected, can you post here your url?

Comment: This is document.URL. Now I can get from this string SPListItemId and SPListId. I think that the issue can be  closed. Many thanks for dialogue and assistance.
`http://apps-58fe06a08fa74c.srv-devspapps/bugtrack/TestButton4/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fsrv%2Ddevsp%2Fbugtrack&SPLanguage=ru%2DRU&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4569%2E1000&SPAppWebUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fapps%2D58fe06a08fa74c%2Esrv%2Ddevspapps%2Fbugtrack%2FTestButton4&SPListItemId=5&SPListId=%7BC0E84B4A%2D92E7%2D414B%2DACAA%2D88E98824B185%7D&IsDlg=1`